# Function not being called through delegate in Swift

Tags: swift, delegates

I can't get the app to execute changeCard() after abc() finishes executing. The two functions are in different classes. Here is the code below. Any help is appreciated!

```
protocol NetworkControllerDelegate {
    func changeCard()
}

class NetworkController {
    var networkControllerDelegate: NetworkControllerDelegate?

    func abc () {
    //do something here
    networkControllerDelegate?.changeCard()
    }
}

class View: UIViewController, NetworkControllerDelegate {
    var networkController = NetworkController()

    func changeCard() {
    //do something here
    networkController.networkControllerDelegate = self
    }
}
```

I've read all the similar questions on stackoverflow for the past few hours but still can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: If you set two breakpoint, one in `changeCard()` and one in `abc()`. Which order are they called in. Because if `networkControllerDelegate` is nil, nothing will happen when you use it as optional `?`

Comment: So abc() is called first. It seems like changeCard() is never called because my print statement inside changeCard() never executes after abc() executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the following line into viewDidLoad of your view controller so that the delegate is set up prior to use.

```
networkController.networkControllerDelegate = self
```

Also, you might want to think about making the networkControllerDelegate variable in NetworkController weak so as to avoid any retain cycles.